# How to push and pull java files into git

Tags: java, git, github

I am working on a java project. Currently how i am uploading changes to the server is i have run the project in my localhost and create the `.class` files and upload these `.class` files in to the server via ftp. But when i doing things so it is taking lot of tile to upload the files and some times the file upload getting failed before completely uploading.

Currently i started using the git for php. If i started to store the java files in git which will be the best method. Do i need to store the `class` files only on git or i need to store the `.java` files in git.

I need to work work my latest changes on my server when i call a git pull function from the server. Please give me a solution for this.

Answer (score 3):

Git is a version control system for your project. .class files gets generated when you compile your project. So ideally you should avoid storing .class files on Git.

> Automatically generated files like logs or files which get generated by the system like compiled files should be ignored. You can ignore these file by creating .gitignore file.

Comment: Build-control files like an Ant `build.xml` or Maven `pom.xml` should be checked in as well; this provides a repeatable, stable way to reconstruct compiled code from the source.

Comment: Yeah, these files are important for project and should be checked in.

Answer (score 2):

.class files store the java bytecode used by the jvm when you run your code. If you want to be able to run your code remotely after a 'git pull', then I'd recommend pushing the .class files. Otherwise you'll need to use 'javac' to compile them on the remote machine.

As a general rule though, git is primarily used for source code. .class files are something you'd usually see in .gitignore, since compiling remotely isn't terrible, especially if you include a makefile in your repository.

Edit: Another reason you might want to refrain from committing .class files is that they might not run on different versions of the jvm. Compiling locally ensures that the .class files generated will run on that machines version of the jvm.

Answer (score 0):

`Java` files and resources like `properties, xml, makefiles` that allow reconstructing the entire build should be added to git. Also, if you don't use `Maven`(you should!), you should add the jars you use to git too. This way, every time a new developer is checking out your project, he has everything to compile and run it.

Avoid(add to .gitignore):

```
- class files(target/build folder?)
- credentials
- log files(or any possible output)
```

Comment: yah this way is ok for developers, but how can i pull the changes to server using the above method?

Comment: @Optimizer I'm not sure I understand what you want. Can you please explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: i want my developers each day work needs to upload in git in a seperate branch. And after the issue fixed i need to merge these changes to master and need to pull those changes to server also. But if i store java files in git the there is no use when i call git pull. Becuase it produces on java files on server. My requirement is when i pull all class files needs to upload to server and when i restart the tomcat the changes will effect on server! cool!.

Comment: Oh, so you basically want to store java files and when you pull you want to auto compile and generate the class files? I am not sure if it is possible, but you can build it right after the pull on the server. Your best shot is a git hook.

Comment: yah i will try that. Thanks Sliviu